# Checking the return value of a function in a macro

Tags: c, unix, macros, c-preprocessor, header-files

I have core function which I can call from the customized module of the product.

`function_core` is the core function which will return and integer
we have a macro in header file:

```
#define func_cust function_core
```

I am calling 
`func_cust` inside my customized code.
But inside the core we again call some other core function:

```
 #define function_core main_core
```

so I cannot put in my customized code all the arguments.

I am calling this `func_cust` function call in many **C** files.

I need to check the return value of the function `function_core` like 
if `function_core` returns x then I want to change the return value to 0  or else same return value will be returned.

For example I want to define a macro like this:

```
#define funct_cust ((function_core==x)?0:function_core)
```

Is this possible?

To be more specific this is what i need!!

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define sum_2 ((sum_1==11)?0:sum_1)
#define sum_1(a,b) sum(a,b)
int sum( int ,int);

int main()
{
int a,b,c;
a=5;
b=6;
c=sum_2(a,b);
printf("%d\n",c);
}

int sum(int x,int y)
{
return x+y;
}
```

this gives an error :

> "test_fun.c", line 12.3: 1506-045 (S) Undeclared identifier sum_1.

I only have the access to play with this macro sum_2.

Comment: Maybe you should show code of your `function_core` and `main_core` etc.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to write an inline function (C99 supports this):

```
static const int x = ...;
static inline int funct_cust(void* args) {
    int res = function_core(args);
    if (res == x) return 0;
    return res;
}
```

If you use gcc, you can use [statement exprs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs):

```
#define funct_cust(args) ({ int res = function_core(args); res == x ? 0 : res; })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can add an actual function, it would be pretty easy:

```
int sanitize(int value, int x)
{
  return (value == x) ? 0 : value;
}
```

Then just change your macro into

```
#define func_cust sanitize(func_core(), x)
```

This solves the otherwise hairy problem of not evaluating the function call twice, and not having to introduce a temporary (which is hard to do in a macro).

If evaluating twice is okay, then of course just do it like you outlined:

```
#define func_cust  func_core() == x ? 0 : func_core()
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to **(assuming a,b is constant)**

```
#define sum_2(a,b) ({(sum_1(a,b)==11)?0:sum_1(a,b);})
#define sum_1 sum
int sum(int ,int);
```

This is not safe because `a,b` can be non constant expressions too. So you may want to create local variables holding the value of a,b so they are only evaluated once **(improved)**

```
#define sum_2(a,b) ({                          \
    typeof(a) _a = (a);                        \
    typeof(b) _b = (b);                        \
    sum_1(_a, _b) == 11 ? 0 : sum_1(_a,_b);    \
})
#define sum_1 sum
int sum(int ,int);
```

Do not miss any of the curly braces, semi-colon in the last statement, and the slashes.